# c# code double_it is not working when doubling an integer's value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial on udemy, and my question is if the c# code double_it is no longer used by unity3d, or if there's some type of library I have to include in my code for it to work. The couse had me write the following code, in order to double an integer's value. The other problem is that I cannot get a variable named temp to work either in my code. It's all part of the same code.

```
    void Start ()
    {       
            int anumber;
        anumber = double_it (5);
        Debug.Log ("The doubled value is: " + anumber);
    }

    void Update () 
    {       
            if double_it(int input_number) {
            var temp = input_number * 2;
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if double_it(int input_number)` is not valid C# syntax. Are you sure `double_it` wasn't defined somewhere earlier in the lesson?

Comment: What's so bad with doing `anumber *= 2`. And there's nothing about a `double_it` function in the Unity documentation.

Comment: @CNuts You didn't read his code, he has the double_it method somewhat defined in the middle of the Update. He needs to get his syntax correct first.

Comment: @ChuckSavage oh didn't realize that was a method, yeah you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Most commonly, methods are defined separate from one another. I won't go into the more complex situations, but for your code to work, the double_it method must be a global function.

```
void Start ()
{       
    int anumber;
    anumber = double_it (5);
    Debug.Log ("The doubled value is: " + anumber);
}

void Update () 
{       
}

int double_it(int input_number) 
{
    var temp = input_number * 2;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you to both. I will also submit a revised version to my teacher, just so other people know what the correct syntax is. I also tried looking for double_it in the unity documentation, but nothing was there. Anyways, I will try the code again, and will post if everything works or not soon!

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer by just following the error codes in MonoDevelop and this is what I got. Well, at least there are no compiler errors this way. I also found that MonoDevelop does not refresh each line of code, until you physically go up or/and down with the arrow.

```
    void Start()
    {
        int anumber;
        anumber = double_it (5);
        Debug.Log ("The doubled value is: " + anumber);
        anumber = double_it (12);
        Debug.Log ("The doubled value is: " + anumber);
    }

    void Update()
            {

        if (Input.GetKey ("Right")) {
            transform.Translate (.2f, 0f, 0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey ("Left")) {
            transform.Translate (-.2f, 0f, 0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey ("Up")) {
            transform.Translate (0f, .2f, 0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey ("Down")) {
            transform.Translate (0f, -.2f, 0f);
        }
        }
        int double_it(int input_number)
        {
            var temp = input_number * 2;
            return temp;
        }
    }
```